# I would like + please

Tags: conversation

I received an email with this sentence:

- He gives a talk and then I and anyone else interested can discuss with him afterward.

In response to that sentence, can I write this next sentence or not? How is the best way of responding to it?

- I would also like to talk to him after his talk, please.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Comment: "The below example" or more likely "the example below" does not sound especially stilted in Britain. Though in this case I agree that "the following sentence" would have been better. It really depends where the sentence/example appears. If it sits at the bottom of the page "the example below" is what I would use.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be better to say, "I would like to speak with him after his talk." That way you avoid using the word "talk" twice in the same sentence.

Comment: Or 'join in the discussion'.

Comment: I would also like to join the discussion. Is it? @KateBunting

Comment: @Marco Yes, that would be OK.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes. And the sentence he received is itself not free from problems. "Discuss" is usually a transitive verb. Someone will potentially disagree with me here. And I haven't checked the OED. But personally I like to "discuss something". For me it has to have a direct object, as well as the ablative. "Please discuss with Charlie" unless it is understood what is to be discussed is, in my view inept. Yes, as I thought the OED does recognise an intransitive use which has been on the scene since the 16th century. But I don't especially like it.